# How to get the GTK version information in a GtkSharp application (C#)?

Tags: gtk, gtk#

I have searched the web and found Python code `Gtk.MAJOR_VERSION`, Vala code `Gtk.get_major_version()` but there seems to be nothing similar in GtkSharp.

Comment: There is a [`Global` class with a `CheckVersion` method](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Global.CheckVersion(System.UInt32%2cSystem.UInt32%2cSystem.UInt32))... but the docs says not to use this...

Comment: Also, it does not return the current version, it only checks if the version you pass to it is valid.